# Allow to update all table attributes or just the attributes that 's not a part of the key?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

If I have table with the following structure :

[image]

in the user interface there 's a grid which consists of dropdownlist for the dates in month (`dayDate`) and dropdownlist for the employees(`empNum`) and dropdownlist for the shifts (`shiftId`),the `recordId` is read from session

My question is :

- What are the properties should i allow the user to update after the
  insertion ?
- Should i allow only to change the `shiftId` cuz it's not a part of
  **the key**? or allow to update all properties except the  `recordId` and in this case how to handle updating attributes as a part of table
  key ?

Comment: if you want to update any of the other fields you will have to make sure that your record is still unique before going through with the edit as you will be running into unique constraints if you don't, shiftId can be edited without any problem

Comment: @JeremyC:how to check the uniqueness ? by catching the exception or there's other way ?

Comment: you could do a select on the values you are trying to change it to first, then if you don't receive a row in the select you can go through with the update, but I advise against updating your primary keys, I would suggest altering your table so you would have a single primary key instead of a concatenated one